# The fastest way to read from MDB to Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

I want to read a relatively large table from an `MDB` file and save its fields to a `Dictionary`. This is a one time operation and I will not need to `UPDATE` or `INSERT INTO` database after that. So I only need a `SELECT` query.

What is the fastest way to do this. Using Datasets seems slow:

```
var con = new OleDbConnection();
const string dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;";
const string dbSource = "Data Source = D:/programming/Frames.mdb";

con.ConnectionString = dbProvider + dbSource;
con.Open();
const string query = "SELECT * FROM [Concrete Design 1 - Column Summary Data - ACI 318-99]";
var dt = new DataTable();
var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
da.Fill(dt);


for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  // Create Dictionary here
}
```

I know using the below method will be faster but I just don't know how to get it right:

```
var con = new OleDbConnection();
const string dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;";
const string dbSource = "Data Source = D:/programming/Frames.mdb";
con.ConnectionString = dbProvider + dbSource;
var cmd = new OleDbCommand { Connection = con };
con.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Concrete Design 1 - Column Summary Data - ACI 318-99]";


// I don't know how get the fields and rows from the database

con.Close();
```

Comment: What do you want to store as key and what as value?

Comment: The first field as key and the other fields will be defined as a properties in a class and set as dictionary's value.

Comment: Indeed, lots of other things to worry about when you use Jet.  Keeping it going for a couple of months without data corruption is a a major effort.  Not speed, it is a pretty efficient ISAM.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not using it as my primary database, the file happens to be the output of some software and I only want read its data.

Comment: That's just disk speed.  An SSD is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most efficient approach is using a `DataReader` to stream the data into the `Dictionary`. You can use `DataReader.FieldCount` to get the number of fields.

Here is an example using a custom class that holds all fields:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<object, Record>();
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        object key = reader[0];
        Record rec = new Record(key);
        for(int i=0; i< reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            rec.Fields.Add(reader[i]);
        }
        dict.Add(key, rec);
    }
}
```

Here's the class, use the correct types and multiple properties instead of the list if possible:

```
public class Record
{
    public Record(object key)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        Fields = new List<object>();
    }
    public object Key;
    public List<object> Fields;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked it didn't make much difference in my case. :(

Comment: I chose this answer. Although it didn't improve the sped much but it is good for memory :P

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check if a datareader with a loop while reader read is faster to add item to your dictionnary.